# How to publish WordPress site built in WebMatrix

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, webmatrix, publishing

This is a 3 part question/advice. I built a WordPress site locally using WebMatrix a while back and had to upload it to GoDaddy. This was a mission, i couldn't get it to work no matter what i tried so i figured i was doing something wrong. Called them a few times and didn't get any help, until i called someone who had dealt with this before (think he said that he built a site the same way) and knew exactly how to get it working. I tried doing another site and went through the same issues publishing and couldn't upload it because i didn't write down what they told me to do the first time, and nobody else knows how to get this to work. So...
1- Is there a different hosting provider that I should use (I have a WordPress site on WebMatrix at home that I need to publish) that works better/easier with WebMatrix/Web Deploy?

2 - Is there a different/better tool you recommend for me to use other than WebMatrix for Wordpress? (WebMatrix installs WordPress automatically for me and gives me intellisense and other useful tools so I use it thanks to that)

3 - This is the most important, How can i publish a WP site that i completely built locally using WebMatrix when I'm ready? (i think there's plugins i need to download to re-route url's or something like that. And i think i need to edit the wp-config file too, not sure. A step by step from someone would be priceless)

I've searched every way i could think of when i was trying to publish the site a bit ago i seem to have read everything i could find and still couldn't figure it out. Any help would be great so that when im ready to publish the site i built at home i can get it up and running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest place to look for hosting for WebMatrix built sites is the Windows Web Hosting Gallery:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home

You can see a demo of setting up a site with Arvixe and deploying from WebMatrix (though not WordPress) here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnTZdaiqlrU

**Shameless Plug**

You can also easily use Microsoft Azure to host WebMatrix sites, and WordPress.  Here's an article that describes how to set it up:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Faith-Allington-Does-WordPress-in-WebMatrix-and-Deploys-Into-Windows-Azure-Web-Sites

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liVozPQaaRY

Hope this all helps!